# Why is only the last input value displayed on screen?

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs, input

I'm having problem with my input fields. I got five of them. When i fill all of them and press the button to display them on the screen, only the last one I typed is displayed on all places... (this was hard to formulate, ask if you don't understand)

Here is when i want the output:

´´´

```
{this.state.new_array.map((char, i) => (
     <li key={i}>
        {`(${char.gender})
           ${char.name}
           ${char.height}
           ${char.eye_color}
           ${char.birth_year}`}
      </li>
```

))}

´´´

Here's my input fields and button:

´´´

```
<input  onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
<input  onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
<input  onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
<input  onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
<input  onChange={this.handleChange}></input>
<button onClick={this.addNewCharacter} }>Add character</button>
```

´´´

And here's my functions connected to button and inputs:

´´´

```
 constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            new_array: [],
            nameFromInput: "",
            heightFromInput: "",
            birthyearFromInput: "",
            genderFromInput: "",
            eyecolorFromInput: ""
        }
    }

addNewCharacter = () => {
        this.setState(oldState => ({
            new_array: [...oldState.new_array, { // IM PRETTY SURE IT HAS TO DO WITH THIS FUCNTION?
                name: this.state.nameFromInput, 
                height: this.state.heightFromInput,
                birth_year: this.state.birthyearFromInput,
                gender: this.state.genderFromInput,
                eye_color: this.state.eyecolorFromInput
            }]
        }))
        this.setState({showFavorites: true})
    }

 handleChange = event => {
        this.setState({
            nameFromInput: event.target.value,
            heightFromInput: event.target.value,
            birthyearFromInput: event.target.value,
            genderFromInput: event.target.value,
            eyecolorFromInput: event.target.value});
    }
```

´´´

Answer (score 0):

Every time you change *any* of the input fields' values, you're calling `this.handleChange`, the same function every time, with that input change Event passed as an argument.

No matter which input this event is fired from, every key in the state gets updated with the value from that input.

Something that might look a little better is:

```
generateHandleChange = key => event => {
  this.setState({[key]: event.target.value});
};
```

and your inputs would look like this:

```html
<input onChange={this.generateHandleChange('name')} />
<input onChange={this.generateHandleChange('height')} />
<input onChange={this.generateHandleChange('birth_year')} />
<input onChange={this.generateHandleChange('gender')} />
<input onChange={this.generateHandleChange('eye_color')} />
<button onClick={this.addNewCharacter}>Add character</button>
```

Comment: @gospecomid12 u need to put `:` instead of `,` after `[key]`. check the edit :)

Comment: I does'nt work now, nothing is sent from the input fields? Only the text between like " ... is ... year old and has ... eyes"

Comment: @opr It's ok i figured it out by myself! But thanks for the time invested!:)

Answer (score 0):

Why make something so easy complicated?

Here's a working sample in Codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/serene-hodgkin-d5kz9?file=/src/App.js

Solution posted below for brevity:

```
import React from "react";

export default class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      name: "",
      height: "",
      birthyear: "",
      gender: "",
      eyecolor: ""
    };
  }

  handleChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      name: event.target.value,
      height: event.target.value,
      birthyear: event.target.value,
      gender: event.target.value,
      eyecolor: event.target.value
    });
  };

  addNewCharacter = () => {
    const { name, height, birth_year, gender, eye_color } = this.state;
    this.setState({
      new_array: {
        name,
        height,
        birth_year,
        gender,
        eye_color
      },
      showFavorites: true
    });
    console.log(this.state);
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <input onChange={this.handleChange} />
        <button onClick={this.addNewCharacter}>Add character</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This still dont work, i still get the value from the last touched input field to all of the places. But much nicer code!

Comment: @gospecomid12 what last touched edit? i don't understand

Comment: Yes, the value in the last edited input field is the value that is displayed over all 5 outputs. Lets say that i edit name to "ooo" then "ooo" is displayed on gender, height, birth_year......

Comment: @gospecomid12 i don't understand why it isn't working? click on the codesandbox link to see for yourself :)

Comment: look at this: https://gyazo.com/50c4658010b504d74a208237cbbe4483
all gets "ooo" because i wrote it in last

Comment: It's ok i figured it out by myself! But thanks for the time invested!:)

Comment: @gospecomid12 maybe post an answer so we can all learn from it :)